# How to created (double?) nest rows in Bootstrap 3 and vertically align?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.4 and I cannot figure out how to nest a column on each side of two columns. I can get the left side, and the middle two .col-sm-6 but the far right column will not align vertically to the top.

The middle columns are also images with text overlaid, and I cannot seem to figure out how to vertically align the text.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

did not work, unless I am overlooking something very simple of where to place it?

Here is the simplified code below, but the codepen link will most defiantly help illustrate the problem.

http://codepen.io/ethanethan/pen/NGeoqp

```
<section>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">



   <!-- tall left column ad -->
            <div class="col-sm-3 ads">
              <h1>Ad Placed on the Left!</h1>
            </div>


<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="row">

   <!-- img 1 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>

   <!-- img 2 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="row">

   <!-- img 3 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>

   <!-- img 4 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="row">

   <!-- img 5 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>

   <!-- img 6 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>

  </div>
</div>

   <!-- tall left column ad -->
            <div class="col-sm-3 ads">
              <h1>Ad Placed on the Right!</h1>
            </div>



       </div>
     </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your html structure and then change their classes. You have to wrap all parents of `slide`(`.col-sm-6`) by a div(`.col-sm-6`) and then change `.col-sm-6` to `.col-sm-12`. However, I fixed your problem and for centering vertically I used  `display: flex;`.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/ojJmYK?editors=110)

Comment: @user122552 Does it fix your problem?

Comment: Is there anyway to vertically align the divs at the top? Also, the **flex** sort of works, but it doesn't collapse like a normal Bootstrap grid. The side ads still stay on the sides.

Comment: @user122552 Do you mean [this](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/ojJmYK?editors=110)?